# Get records count from Business connector

Tags: c#, axapta, x++, business-connector

I am using the following code to get the record count from .NET Business Connector:

```
DynRec = DynAx.CreateAxaptaRecord("AddressCountryRegion");
DynRec.ExecuteStmt("select count(Name) from %1 where %1.Name like'I*'");
if (DynRec.Found)
    MessageBox.Show((string)DynRec.get_Field("Name"));
```

Is there a better way to it? For example, get the record count as an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ax you typically do a count on the RecId field. This is an int or int64 depending on your version of Ax.

Comment: Thank You. RecId is the way to go!